# Why does replication fail with error Duplicate entry for key?

Tags: mysql, replication, keys

We have been replicating for a year or two now with little problem. Sometimes we get an erroneous SQL query which stops replications, and we use the following commands to get it going again:

```
STOP SLAVE;
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;
START SLAVE;
SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G;
```

This is usually fine, however today we've started getting errors while trying to replicate a (FYI Invision Power Board) database:

```
               Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'forums-pid-994' for key '
app'' on query. Default database: 'forum_db'. Query: 'INSERT INTO ibf_rep
utation_cache (`app`,`type`,`type_id`,`rep_like_cache`) VALUES('forums','pid',99
4,'a:2:{s:10:\"cache_data\";a:0:{}s:12:\"cache_expire\";i:1326339370;}') ON DUPL
ICATE KEY UPDATE app=VALUES(app),type=VALUES(type),type_id=VALUES(type_id),rep_l
ike_cache=VALUES(rep_like_cache)'
```

There are many queries like this it seems as part of the Invision Power Board software so getting rid of it isn't a choice. The weird thing is, when I run that exact query on the same MySQL server it goes through without problem.

**Note:** We upgraded from MySQL 5.1.36 to MySQL 5.5.16 yesterday so this is almost certainly related. It is on a Windows server.

Here is the layout of the table:

```
mysql> DESC forum_db.ibf_reputation_cache;
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |

+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

| id             | bigint(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |

| app            | varchar(32)         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |

| type           | varchar(32)         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |

| type_id        | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |

| rep_points     | int(10)             | NO   |     | 0       |                |

| rep_like_cache | mediumtext          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |

+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

6 rows in set (0.12 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the error message:

```
               Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Duplicate entry 'forums-pid-994' for key '
app'' on query. Default database: 'forum_db'. Query: 'INSERT INTO ibf_rep
utation_cache (`app`,`type`,`type_id`,`rep_like_cache`) VALUES('forums','pid',99
4,'a:2:{s:10:\"cache_data\";a:0:{}s:12:\"cache_expire\";i:1326339370;}') ON DUPL
ICATE KEY UPDATE app=VALUES(app),type=VALUES(type),type_id=VALUES(type_id),rep_l
ike_cache=VALUES(rep_like_cache)'
```

Replication is **complaining about the index called `app`.** Evidently, you have a UNIQUE index on that column. Also, note the query's `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause. You have `app=VALUES(app)`. This column cannot be replaced in `ON DUPLICATE KEY` for two reasons:

1. it is the same column that triggered the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` action
2. it will needlessly affect the index `app` if the action were allowed

Recommendation : You should remove `app=VALUES(app)` from the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause.

It is possible that previous versions of MySQL simply ignored offending columns in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause and the latest version you are now using is more aware of this issue.

Comment: Although I can't do this (it's off-the-shelf software) it is the right answer - I will show the developers this message and see if they can sort something out. Thanks :)